# DatePicker обнуляемый

Tags: c#, uwp, xamarin.forms

Задача, есть кроссплотформенное мобильное приложение, на данном этапе я на **uwp**
для поля **дата** необходим сброс и задать **нулевое значение**, на данный момент DatePicker по умолчанию не позволяет сбросить и обнулить дату.
Если кто уже сталкивался подскажите как можно поле дата обнулить или например с помощью дизайна показать, что поле пустое, например placeholder.

> На счет меток, приложение мобильное Xamarin.Forms и UWP не чистый а от
> Xamarin Forms...

Comment: Нулевая дата в понимании UNIX Time - это 1 января 1970 года. А что в вашем понимании нулевая дата? Я не знаю, что поддерживает данный контрол, но может его значениею можно присвоить `null`?

Comment: 0001-01-01 00:00:00.0000000 базаДанныхSql принимает параметр нуль для даты, это не формат юникс, а иной.
Мобильное приложение должно "сбрасывать" пользователю дату и показывать что оно пустое, чтобы пользователь понимал, что нужно ввести данные. К сожалению как я указала выше не принимает значение нуль пикер контрол

Comment: Задай по умолчанию текущую дату

Comment: Можно сделать nullable в бд и писать `null`

Comment: по умолчанию на сегодня стоит текущая дата, в базе данных уже сделано нюлабль, вопрос больше пользовательского характера.
Я нашла очень интересное [решение](https://xamgirl.com/clearable-datepicker-in-xamarin-forms/), но пока не очень получается адаптировать под uwp, есть некое [решение](https://github.com/CrossGeeks/ClearableDatePickerSample/issues/10), по моему это чистый uwp, так как у меня нету доступа к DateField , что он указал в параметре [метода SetNullableText](https://gist.github.com/stewartsims/248f7c8987aeed50d71f79934f85ae37)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*напомню контрол для даты обнуляемой*
[тут для IOS и Андроид](https://xamgirl.com/clearable-datepicker-in-xamarin-forms/)

[тут для **UWP**](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1150865/%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5-%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B4-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B4-uwpxamarinforms/1153513#1153513) прекрасное решение для **обнуляемой даты** календаря и дизайн симпатичный,
**для** **всех платформ** теперь решение адаптивное и рабочее

класс контрол

```
using System;
using Xamarin.Forms;

namespace NullableDatePicker.Controls
{
    public class NullableDatePicker : DatePicker
    {
        public NullableDatePicker()
        {
            Format = "d";
        }
        public string _originalFormat = null;

        public static readonly BindableProperty PlaceHolderProperty =
            BindableProperty.Create(nameof(PlaceHolder), typeof(string), typeof(NullableDatePicker), "/ . / . /");

        public string PlaceHolder
        {
            get { return (string)GetValue(PlaceHolderProperty); }
            set
            {
                SetValue(PlaceHolderProperty, value);
            }
        }


        public static readonly BindableProperty NullableDateProperty =
        BindableProperty.Create(nameof(NullableDate), typeof(DateTime?), typeof(NullableDatePicker), null, defaultBindingMode: BindingMode.TwoWay);

        public DateTime? NullableDate
        {
            get { return (DateTime?)GetValue(NullableDateProperty); }
            set { SetValue(NullableDateProperty, value); UpdateDate(); }
        }

        private void UpdateDate()
        {
            if (NullableDate != null)
            {
                if (_originalFormat != null){
                    Format = _originalFormat;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                Format = PlaceHolder;

            }

        }
        protected override void OnBindingContextChanged()
        {
            base.OnBindingContextChanged();
            if (BindingContext != null)
            {
                _originalFormat = Format;
                UpdateDate();
            }
        }

        protected override void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName = null)
        {
            base.OnPropertyChanged(propertyName);

            if (propertyName == DateProperty.PropertyName || (propertyName == IsFocusedProperty.PropertyName && !IsFocused && (Date.ToString("d") == DateTime.Now.ToString("d"))))
            {
                AssignValue();
            }

            if (propertyName == NullableDateProperty.PropertyName && NullableDate.HasValue)
            {
                Date = NullableDate.Value;
                if (Date.ToString(_originalFormat) == DateTime.Now.ToString(_originalFormat))
                {
                    //this code was done because when date selected is the actual date the"DateProperty" does not raise  
                    UpdateDate();
                }
            }
        }

        public void CleanDate()
        {
            NullableDate = null;
            UpdateDate();
        }
        public void AssignValue()
        {
            NullableDate = Date;
            UpdateDate();

        }
    }
}
```

использование

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms" 
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml" 
             x:Class="NullableDatePicker.MainPage"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:NullableDatePicker.Controls" >
    <ContentPage.Content>
        <StackLayout VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" Padding="20">
            <Label Text="Select Date:"/>
            <local:NullableDatePicker NullableDate="{Binding MyDate}" />
        </StackLayout>
    </ContentPage.Content>
</ContentPage>
```