# Контрол нулабл с android/ios на uwp

Tags: c#, uwp, xamarin.forms

как можно подогнать код под другие платформы, незная синтаксиса [код](https://xamgirl.com/clearable-datepicker-in-xamarin-forms/) реализованный для IOS и Android под UWP

android

```
using System;
using Xamarin.Forms;
using Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android;
using Android.App;
using Android.Widget;
using System.ComponentModel;
using NullableDatePicker.Droid;

[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(NullableDatePicker.Controls.NullableDatePicker), typeof(NullableDatePickerRenderer))]
namespace NullableDatePicker.Droid
{
    public class NullableDatePickerRenderer : ViewRenderer<Controls.NullableDatePicker, EditText>
    {
        DatePickerDialog _dialog;
        protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Controls.NullableDatePicker> e)
        {
            base.OnElementChanged(e);

            this.SetNativeControl(new Android.Widget.EditText(Forms.Context));
            if (Control == null || e.NewElement == null)
                return;

            this.Control.Click += OnPickerClick;
            this.Control.Text = Element.Date.ToString(Element.Format);
            this.Control.KeyListener = null;
            this.Control.FocusChange += OnPickerFocusChange;
            this.Control.Enabled = Element.IsEnabled;

        }

        protected override void OnElementPropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnElementPropertyChanged(sender, e);

            if (e.PropertyName == Xamarin.Forms.DatePicker.DateProperty.PropertyName || e.PropertyName == Xamarin.Forms.DatePicker.FormatProperty.PropertyName)
                SetDate(Element.Date);
        }

        void OnPickerFocusChange(object sender, Android.Views.View.FocusChangeEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.HasFocus)
            {
                ShowDatePicker();
            }
        }

        protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
        {
            if (Control != null)
            {
                this.Control.Click -= OnPickerClick;
                this.Control.FocusChange -= OnPickerFocusChange;

                if (_dialog != null)
                {
                    _dialog.Hide();
                    _dialog.Dispose();
                    _dialog = null;
                }
            }

            base.Dispose(disposing);
        }

        void OnPickerClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            ShowDatePicker();
        }

        void SetDate(DateTime date)
        {
            this.Control.Text = date.ToString(Element.Format);
            Element.Date = date;
        }

        private void ShowDatePicker()
        {
            CreateDatePickerDialog(this.Element.Date.Year, this.Element.Date.Month - 1, this.Element.Date.Day);
            _dialog.Show();
        }

        void CreateDatePickerDialog(int year, int month, int day)
        {
            Controls.NullableDatePicker view = Element;
            _dialog = new DatePickerDialog(Context, (o, e) =>
           {
               view.Date = e.Date;
               ((IElementController)view).SetValueFromRenderer(VisualElement.IsFocusedProperty, false);
               Control.ClearFocus();
               _dialog = null;
           }, year, month, day);

            _dialog.SetButton("Done", (sender, e) =>
           {
               SetDate(_dialog.DatePicker.DateTime);
               this.Element.Format = this.Element._originalFormat;
               this.Element.AssignValue();
           });
            _dialog.SetButton2("Clear", (sender, e) =>
            {
                this.Element.CleanDate();
                Control.Text = this.Element.Format;
            });
        }
    }
}
```

ios

```
using System;
using Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS;
using Xamarin.Forms;
using UIKit;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using NullableDatePicker.iOS;

[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(NullableDatePicker.Controls.NullableDatePicker), typeof(NullableDatePickerRenderer))]
namespace NullableDatePicker.iOS
{
    public class NullableDatePickerRenderer : DatePickerRenderer
    {
        protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<DatePicker> e)
        {
            base.OnElementChanged(e);

            if (e.NewElement != null && this.Control != null)
            {
                this.AddClearButton();

                this.Control.BorderStyle = UITextBorderStyle.Line;
                Control.Layer.BorderColor = UIColor.LightGray.CGColor;
                Control.Layer.BorderWidth = 1;

                if (Device.Idiom == TargetIdiom.Tablet)
                {
                    this.Control.Font = UIFont.SystemFontOfSize(25);
                }
            }

        }

        private void AddClearButton()
        {
            var originalToolbar = this.Control.InputAccessoryView as UIToolbar;

            if (originalToolbar != null && originalToolbar.Items.Length <= 2)
            {
                var clearButton = new UIBarButtonItem("Clear", UIBarButtonItemStyle.Plain, ((sender, ev) =>
                {
                    NullableDatePicker.Controls.NullableDatePicker baseDatePicker = this.Element as NullableDatePicker.Controls.NullableDatePicker;
                    this.Element.Unfocus();
                    this.Element.Date = DateTime.Now;
                    baseDatePicker.CleanDate();
                }));

                var newItems = new List<UIBarButtonItem>();
                foreach (var item in originalToolbar.Items)
                {
                    newItems.Add(item);
                }

                newItems.Insert(0, clearButton);

                originalToolbar.Items = newItems.ToArray();
                originalToolbar.SetNeedsDisplay();
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Приложение кроссплотформенное Mobile Xamarin.Forms, нужна адаптация под UWP Xamarin Forms
[тут](https://gist.github.com/stewartsims/248f7c8987aeed50d71f79934f85ae37) что то предлагается, но у меня не получается переписать под UWP, и плюс [тут](https://github.com/CrossGeeks/ClearableDatePickerSample/issues/10) говорится про адаптацию IOS под UWP, но самого кода не прилагается

[вопрос заданный раннее](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1150762/datepicker-%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%BD%D1%83%D0%BB%D1%8F%D0%B5%D0%BC%D1%8B%D0%B9)

Comment: Здесь не делают работу за вас. Здесь отвечают на вопросы.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
using FoodPicker.App.Controls.NullableDateTimePickerControl.View;
using FoodPicker.App.Controls.NullableDateTimePickerControl.ViewModel;
using System;
using System.Globalization;
using Xamarin.Forms;
using Xamarin.Forms.Xaml;

namespace FoodPicker.App.Controls
{
    [XamlCompilation(XamlCompilationOptions.Compile)]
    public partial class NullableDateTimePicker : ContentView
    {
        // if binded true call event.
        public event EventHandler<EventArgs> DataChange;
        bool binded = false;

        /// <summary>
        /// Title label for DisplayDate.
        /// </summary>
        public static readonly BindableProperty TitleProperty = BindableProperty.Create(nameof(Title), typeof(string), typeof(NullableDateTimePicker), string.Empty, propertyChanged: OnTitleChanged);
        /// <summary>
        /// String Display for Date Selected.
        /// </summary>
        public static readonly BindableProperty DateProperty = BindableProperty.Create(nameof(Date), typeof(DateTime?), typeof(NullableDateTimePicker), DateTime.Now, BindingMode.TwoWay, propertyChanged: OnDateChanged);

        public NullableDateTimePicker()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        public string Title
        {
            get => (string)GetValue(TitleProperty);
            set => SetValue(TitleProperty, value);
        }
        public DateTime? Date
        {
            get => (DateTime?)GetValue(DateProperty);
            set => SetValue(DateProperty, value);
        }

        private static void OnTitleChanged(BindableObject bindable, object oldValue, object newValue)
        {
            if(bindable is NullableDateTimePicker control && newValue is string title)
            {
                control.HeaderLabel.Text = title;
            }
        }

        private static void OnDateChanged(BindableObject bindable, object oldValue, object newValue)
        {
            var dateTimePicker = (NullableDateTimePicker)bindable;
            var datetime = (DateTime?)newValue;

            if (datetime != null)
            {
                dateTimePicker.SelectedDateEntry.Text = ((DateTime)datetime).ToString("f", CultureInfo.CurrentCulture);
            }
            else
            {
                dateTimePicker.SelectedDateEntry.Text = null;
            }

            if (dateTimePicker.binded)
                dateTimePicker.DataChange?.Invoke(dateTimePicker, new EventArgs());
        }

        private void EntryTapped(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var calendarViewModel = new CalendarViewModel();

            if (Date != null)
                calendarViewModel.DateChoice = Date.Value;

            CalendarPage calendarPage = new CalendarPage(calendarViewModel); 

            Navigation.PushAsync(calendarPage);

            MessagingCenter.Subscribe<CalendarViewModel, DateTime>(this, CalendarViewModel.DateValidatedEvent, OnDateTimeValidated, calendarViewModel);
        }

        private void OnDateTimeValidated(CalendarViewModel arg1, DateTime newDate)
        {
            MessagingCenter.Unsubscribe<CalendarViewModel, DateTime>(this, CalendarViewModel.DateValidatedEvent);
            Date = newDate;
            Navigation.PopAsync();
        }

        private void OnDeleteButtonTapped(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Date = null;
        }

        private void OnTodayButtonTapped(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Date = DateTime.Now;
        }

        protected override void OnBindingContextChanged()
        {
            base.OnBindingContextChanged();

            if (BindingContext != null)
            {
                if (binded)
                    return;

                binded = true;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

решение найдено, и всегда чего то нам не хватает
**то, что сейчас**

[image: на сегодня у меня это]

**то, что необходимо**

[image: а мне бы надобно это]